# How to dump VXLAN/VLAN ID in packet capture?

Tags: linux, tcpdump, tshark

Is there anyway to use tcpdump or any other linux tool to know VXLAN ID/VLAN ID while capturing packet on interfaces?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `vlan.id` filter in your command.

You can see more filters here:

http://packetlife.net/media/library/13/Wireshark_Display_Filters.pdf